# How to send image from html page to the server dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dynamic-data

How can I send a dynamically-created image from a JSP page to the action class using Javascript or jQuery-AJAX? 
I need to send the image file as a file upload with Multipart/form-data.

Comment: i've tried to use var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlHttp.open("POST", "site", true); var formData = new FormData(); formData.append(myimg); xmlHttp.send(formData); but there is some issues in IE8

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to make mutlipart/form-data requests with AJAX. Just gather the image binary and send it as such.

---

Update: based on the sample code you posted:

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", "site", true);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(myimg);
xmlHttp.send(formData);
```

Make sure you're using the API correctly. `.append` takes two arguments

```
formData.append("myimg", myimg);
```

Comment: but the FormData() is not supporting in IE8

Comment: You can manually make a multipart/form-data request. It's a bit involved and since I'm no longer supporting IE8 I don't have the code for it that I used.

Comment: No need to manually make a MPE request.  Just submit a form in older browsers.